# Applying virtualization for DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, virtualization

I have a datagrid where I've customize the headers to have textbox in every column to have filtering feature, something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering

My datagrid is wrapped around a groupbox. It is binded to a ICollectionView so that I can apply filtering to it my calling collectionView.CustomFilter.

Whenever I do the filtering, I notice that the filtering process is slow. Let's say if I key in a letter in a textbox which is suppose to filter out some rows, I will notice about 0.5-1 second lag. How can I improve the performance of the filtering process?

I've set these but I do not see any difference, still laggy..

```
EnableRowVirtualization="True"
EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I've already provided a fix height for my datagrid.

Comment: I don't think there is much left for you to do in WPF prospects. Can you give you filter logic of collection view?

Comment: Not much, just something like this. collectionView.CustomFilter = "title like '*filter*'";

Comment: I don't think you can do much here. if every thing is just plain simple then it will take the time what it has to take for refresh. you must be binding a large no of records to grid. what kind of collection are you using  a list,bindinglist or observablecollection? are you using templates for Datagrid?

Comment: My data are in a datatable, and since I need the filtering capabilities, I need to use BindingList which supports CustomFilter. My data has around 10 rows and 8 columns..I believe that's not alot but I can still feel lag when filtering

Comment: I hope you are doing all filtering logic on UI end. DataBase doesn't have to anything once data is brought to UI. Also have you tried using Observablecollection instead of bindinglist. usually that is worth doing on large data. But since you are using CollectionView it's worth trying.

Comment: The number of columns are dynamic according to what I get from the DB, so I don't think I can use ObservableCollection, can I?

Comment: I think so, if you can use BindingList you can also use ObservableCollection in place of that